# KMM: Cast string to NSString get warning "This case can never succeed"

Tags: objective-c, kotlin, xctest, kotlin-multiplatform

In my KMM project, I have a method to invoke Objective-C `predicateWithFormat` method inside it. And when I try to cast the passing string text to NSString, I got this warning "This cast can never succeed".

```
    override fun elementWithPredicateText(text: String): AppElement {
        val predicate = NSPredicate.predicateWithFormat("label CONTAINS %@", text as NSString)
        val query = app.descendantsMatchingType(XCUIElementTypeAny).matchingPredicate(predicate)
        return UIElementWrapper(query)
    }
```

[image]

The problem here if I don't cast this String to NSString, it gets a build error as below screenshot showed. For now with type cast from String to NSString, the build could be successful, although it has this annoying warning, so how could I solve this warning?

[image]

The iOS method which are used.

```
 @kotlin.commonizer.ObjCCallable public open external expect fun predicateWithFormat(predicateFormat: kotlin.String, vararg args: kotlin.Any?): platform.Foundation.NSPredicate { /* compiled code */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe warning you get when casting to `NSString` is a Android Studio or Kotlin compiler bug. It is recommended way to cast Kotlin `String` to `NSString` [see documentation on depreceted method](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlinx.cinterop/-create-n-s-string-from-k-string.html) and [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-objc-interop.html#casting-between-mapped-types).

You can suppress it with `@Suppress("CAST_NEVER_SUCCEEDS")`.

Comment: Yes, I see this page too, the old method is deprecated and they recommend us to use plain kotlin cast to create NSString from String.